# Calling setter from Top Level of Modelclass hierarchy

Tags: java, setter

Imagine you have a model class hierarchy, like

```java
    public class TopLevel {
        private MiddleLevel middleLevel = null;

        public TopLevel() {
            middleLevel = new MiddleLevel();
        }

        public MiddleLevel getMiddleLevel() { return middleLevel; }
    }
```

```java
    public class MiddleLevel {
        private LowLevel lowLevel = null;

        public MiddleLevel () {
            lowLevel = new LowLevel();
        }

        public LowLevel getLowLevel() { return lowLevel; }
    }
```

```java
    public class LowLevel {
        private Value value = null;

        public LowLevel() {
            value = new Value();
        }

        public Value getValue() { return value; }
    }
```

```java
    public class Value {
        private String stringValue = "ItsAValue";
        private String doubleValue = 1.0d;
        private String integerValue = 4321;

        public void setStringValue(String value) {
            stringValue = value;
        }
    }
```

And of course further classes with different attributes. E.g. this hierarchy was created and instantiated by Jaxb.

Now, i want to set a value in the Value-class. Of course i can execute something like:

```java
    TopLevel topLevel = new TopLevel();
    topLevel.getMiddleLevel().getLowLevel().getValue().setStringValue("NewValue");
```

Is there a way to simplify or to generalize this, e.g. to be able to call the "path" through all these class-objects to set a value deep inside? Here is some pseudocode, what i mean:

```java
    public class Anotherclass {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            TopLevel topLevel = new TopLevel();
            setStringValueByPath("topLevel/middleLevel/lowLevel/value/stringValue", "newValue");
            setDoubleValueByPath("topLevel/middleLevel/lowLevel/value/doubleValue", 5.0d);
            setIntegerValueByPath("topLevel/middleLevel/lowLevel/value/integerValue", 1234);
        }

    }
```

Thanks a lot

Alex

Comment: You speak about simplifying, but your simplified calls are longer than the original ones. What benefit do you get?

Comment: based on this "string"-notation (or whatever is possible), i hope, that i can use loops to be able to iterate over parts of this hole model hierarchy and set multiple values at the same time on a more efficient way. My alternative would be to call all "setter-chains" (like above) individually. This would be very "static" for me.

Comment: Sure, there are design patterns which you can use achieve something like this. But it totally depends on why you want to do this. Why can't you take in a `super(Object value)` in your `TopLevel.class` which does the same for you?

Comment: The setter chains are extremely efficient. Much more so than any string manipulation would be.

Comment: @papaya: For me, super() is part of a constructor and must be called from there. At runtime (and after the instantiation of topLevel-object) i want to manipulate this model hierarchy. So i think i need some setter-Methods to go deep into the hierarchy and set a value ...

Comment: @NomadMaker. Yes, of course this might be possible, but its not efficient for me as a programmer to write 100 lines of code, based on these "static setter-chains". The example above is just a minimal example. Usually, e.g. by using Jaxb you map an Xml-File with hundreds of attributes into a large model, with several field variables ... and you want to manipulate such a model-instance on a "nice" way ...

Comment: Then go into the xml objects recursively. It's how I've dealt with xml before.

Comment: What kind of approach would you choose to iterative recusively? The result of Jaxb-Xml-Unmarshaller is actually (in this example) an object of type TopLevel. In a real scenario such a  model hierarchy has many objects in Toplevel.class with individual names.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, if anyone is interested, i think i found a solution, that i was looking for:

A recursive approach based on Java.reflection :

```java
public class ReflectionSetter {
    private static List<Field> getFields(Object object) {
        List<Field> fields = new ArrayList<>();
        fields.addAll(Arrays.asList(object.getClass().getDeclaredFields()));
        return fields;
    }

    private static Field hasField(Object object, String fieldName) {
        for (Field f : getFields(object)) {
            if (f.getName().equalsIgnoreCase(fieldName)) return f;
        }
        return null;
    }

    public static void setValue(Object object, String path, String newValue) throws IllegalArgumentException, IllegalAccessException {
        if (path.contains("/")) {
            int pos = path.indexOf('/');
            String first = path.substring(0, pos);
            String rest = path.substring(pos+1);
            Field f = ReflectionSetter.hasField(object, first);
            if (null == f) throw new IllegalArgumentException("Path not found: " + path);
            f.setAccessible(true);
            Object obj = f.get(object);
            setValue(obj, rest, newValue);
        } else {
            Field f = ReflectionSetter.hasField(object, path);
            if (f == null) throw new IllegalArgumentException("Field not found: " + path);
            // if found -> set value
            f.setAccessible(true);
            f.set(object, newValue);
        }
    }
}
```

Now, you can set a value via a path. Usage:

```java
    TopLevel topLevel = new TopLevel();
    ReflectionSetter.setValue(topLevel, "middleLevel/lowLevel/value/myValue", "NewValue");
```

Answer (score 0):

An ideal efficient way to do this and by focussing more on reducing code complexity and at the same time improving code readability, you should look at design patterns, may be something like [visitor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern) pattern.

> One of the most common use cases of visitor pattern is and as a result of separating algorithm and the data structure, comes with ability to add new operations to existing object structures without modifying said structures.

Moving on to a phase where "*No*, *I want to look at string based approached as pointed in question*". Apache commons library provides something called *JxPath*.
Unsure if you tried looking at **JxPath** [ref.apache.jx.path](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-jxpath/)

> It offers simple interpreter of an expression language called XPath. JXPath applies XPath expressions to graphs of objects of all kinds

Picking an example from your question :

```
TopLevel topLevel = new TopLevel();
JXPathContext context = JXPathContext.newContext(topLevel);
context.setValue("middleLevel/lowLevel/value/stringValue", "newStringValue");
```